# Extract information from a string of data in a CSV file

Tags: python, r, excel

I'm trying to run some analysis on some data and ran into some questions while parsing the data in csv file.

This is the raw data in one cell:

```
{"completed": true, "attempts": 1, "item_state": {"1": {"correct": true, "zone": "zone-7"}, "0": {"correct": true, "zone": "zone-2"}, "2": {"correct": true, "zone": "zone-12"}}, "raw_earned": 1.0}
```

Formatted for clarity:

```
{
  "completed": true,
  "attempts": 1,
  "item_state": {
    "1": {
      "correct": true,
      "zone": "zone-7"
    },
    "0": {
      "correct": true,
      "zone": "zone-2"
    },
    "2": {
      "correct": true,
      "zone": "zone-12"
    }
  },
  "raw_earned": 1.0
}
```

I want to extract only the zone information after each number (`1`, `0`, `2`) and put the results (`zone-7`, `zone-2`, `zone-12`) in separate columns. How can I do that using R or Python?

Comment: Is this JSON? If yes, there are R packages to read this kind of data.

Comment: Yes, that looks like JSON. And yes, you can do that in both R and Python. Both languages are quite excellent for the task. Choose the language that people in your vicinity knows (colleagues, students, etc.), so they might help you.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a dictionary, and when it is stored as an element in a csv, it is stored as a string. In python you can use `ast.literal_Eval()`. It parses strings to `python`ic data types like list, dictionary etc. Also works as data type parser.

If the cell you mentioned is indexed `[i,j]`,

```
import pandas as pd    
import ast
df = pd.read_csv(filename)
a = ast.literal_eval(df.loc[i][j])
b = pd.io.json.json_normalize(a)
output = []
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
  c = ast.literal_eval(df.iloc[i][j])
  temp = pd.DataFrame({'key':c['item_state'].keys(),'zone':[x['zone'] for x in c['item_state'].values()]})
  temp['row_n'] = i
  output.append(temp)
output2 = pd.concat(temp)
```

If `[i,j]` is your cell,
a in the above code is the dictionary as given in your example.
b is a flattened dictionary and contains all key,value pairs in output.

The rest of the code is to extract only the zone values.
If you are looking to apply this for more than one cell, use the loop, else only use the content inside the loop.
output is a list data frames, each of which has the item_state key and zone value as columns and also a row_number for identification.
output2 is concatenated data frame.

ast -  Abstract Syntax Trees

Comment: You are using non standard library first you should note which one and then show the imports in your code as df and pd might not be clear to everyone

Comment: what do you mean by non-standard library?

Comment: I am guessing pd is a pandas import and df is DataFrame which is not mentioned anywhere in your answer and those are not part of python standard library

Answer (score 0):

Convert the cell value to JSON and then you can access any element you would like so:

```
import csv
import json

column_index = 0
state_keys = ['1', '0', '2']
with open('data.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
    for row in reader:
        object = json.loads(row[column_index])
        state = object['item_state']
        # Show all values under item_state in order they appear:
        for key, value in state.items():
            print(state[key]['zone'])
        # Show only state_keys defined in variable in order they are defined in a list
        for key in state_keys:
            print(state[key]['zone'])
```

Comment: What if the numbers change from `1` `2` `0` to other numbers?

Comment: @MichaelKolber This was only to show how easy it is to access any property in such a formatted data

Answer (score 0):

In Python, you can use the `json` library to do something like this:

```py
d = json.loads(raw_cell_data)  # Load the data into a Python dict
results = {}
for key, value in d['item_state'].items():
    results[key] = value['zone']
```

And then you can use `results` to print to a CSV.

Comment: Basically you repeated my answer

Comment: Yes, sorry, I began writing it about 10 minutes ago but stopped to edit the question to clarify it.

Answer (score 0):

The initial situation is a bit unclear, what you show looks like json, but you mention it is in a csv.

assuming you have a csv where the individual fields are strings containing json data, you can extract the zone information by using the csv and json packages.

set up a for loop to iterate over the rows of the csv ([see csv docs for more detail](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)) 
and then use the json module to extract the zone from the string.

```
import csv
import json

# to get ss from a csv:
# my_csv = csv.reader( ... )
# for row in my_csv:
#     ss = row[N]

ss = '{"completed": true, "attempts": 1, "item_state": {"1": {"correct": true, "zone": "zone-7"}, "0": {"correct": true, "zone": "zone-2"}, "2": {"correct": true, "zone": "zone-12"}}, "raw_earned": 1.0}'

jj = json.loads(ss)

for vv in jj['item_state'].values():
    print(vv['zone'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Some thing like this. Not tested as you have not provided sufficient sample.

```
import csv
import json

with open('data.csv') as fr:
    rows = list(csv.reader(fr))

for row in rows:
    data = json.loads(row[0])
    new_col_data = [v['zone'] for v in data['item_state'].values()]
    row.append(", ".join(new_col_data)


with open('new_data.csv', 'w') as fw:
    writer = csv.writer(fw)
    writer.writerows(rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, it looks like each cells data is a dictionary that also contains dictionaries, ie [nested dictionaries](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/nested-dictionary)

If this cell's data were referenced as a variable cell_data, then you can get into the inner "item_state" dictionary with:

```
cell_data["item_state"]
```

this will return

```
{"1": {"correct": true, "zone": "zone-7"}, "0": {"correct": true, "zone": "zone-2"}, "2": {"correct": true, "zone": "zone-12"}}
```

Then you can do the same operation one level deeper by asking for the "1" dictionary:

```
cell_data["item_state"]["1"]
```

returns:

```
{'correct': 'true', 'zone': 'zone-7'}
```

Then once more:

```
cell_data["item_state"]["1"]["zone"]
```

returns

```
'zone-7'
```

So to bring it all together, you could get what you want with the following:

```
your_list = list( cell_data["item_state"][i]['zone'] for i in ["1","0","2"] )
```

returns:

```
['zone-7', 'zone-2', 'zone-12']
```

Answer (score 0):

In R package `rjson`, function `fromJSON` is simple to use.
Any of the following ways of reading the JSON string will produce the same result.

```
library("rjson")

x <- '{"completed": true, "attempts": 1, "item_state": {"1": {"correct": true, "zone": "zone-7"}, "0": {"correct": true, "zone": "zone-2"}, "2": {"correct": true, "zone": "zone-12"}}, "raw_earned": 1.0}'
json <- fromJSON(json_str = x)

# if the string is in a file, say, "so.json"
#json <- fromJSON(file = "so.json")
```

`json` is an object of class `"list"`, make a dataframe out of it.

```
result <- data.frame(zone_num = names(json$item_state))
result <- cbind(result, do.call(rbind.data.frame, json$item_state)[2])

result
#  zone_num    zone
#1        1  zone-7
#0        0  zone-2
#2        2 zone-12
```

Answer (score 0):

get `item_state` and find the value as a `zone` than append key and value to empty list and finally create the new columns with those list

```
zone_val = []
zone_key = []

for k,v in d['item_state'].items():
    zone_val.append(v['zone'])
    zone_key.append(k)

DF[zone_key] = zone_key
DF[zone_val] = zone_val
```